# Maven install error after deleting .m2 folder

Tags: java, maven

I was instructed to delete the .m2 folder as I had a problem with one of the project dependencies but now when I tried to Maven > Clean, then Maven > Install the application I get the following error.

I've tried re-running Maven > Clean, Maven Install several times (as sometime it works this way) but no use. I still get the same error message.

Can someone please advice me how to resolve this problem?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Inventory 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ crm ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ crm ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 73 source files to E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.9\aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.5.10\slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.0.7.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\3.1.3.RELEASE\spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\3.6.0.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar; Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.2.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.2.2\commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-plugin-registry\2.0.6\maven-plugin-registry-2.0.6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-error-diagnostics\2.0.6\maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.0\commons-cli-1.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\2.0.6\maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-model\2.0.6\maven-model-2.0.6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO] 18 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.074s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 16 13:36:32 EET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project crm: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.9\aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.5.10\slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.0.7.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\3.1.3.RELEASE\spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\3.6.0.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar; Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.2.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.2.2\commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-plugin-registry\2.0.6\maven-plugin-registry-2.0.6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-error-diagnostics\2.0.6\maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.0\commons-cli-1.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\2.0.6\maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\vmuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-model\2.0.6\maven-model-2.0.6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole problem resided in that I was right clicking on project folder, selecting Maven > Clean, then Maven > Install. When I right clicked on pom.xml and selected Maven > Install everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you also move the location of the maven repository?

Some maven versions had some trouble with whitespaces in path names. So you may try to change the location in settings.xml - then a `mvn clean install` should re-download everything.

Maybe some of those artifacts are re-downloaded but corrupt? I would then just delete them again and retry. Maybe the jars are HTML files from a proxy?

You can also execute `mvn dependency:go-offline` - this will download also plugins and everything else required to build the project.

Comment: I had everything running smooth for months until I decided to install Apache tiles but then it cause some trouble so I removed the dependency' deleted .m2 folder and tried to maven clean install. Since then and I am getting this error :( I didnt move any file or change any settings

Comment: well it may not be caused by something on your machine. The errors ("invalid LOC header (bad signature)") indicate a corrupted jar file. So maybe maven central was broken at that time, or the network or a maven proxy of you use one. The way to go is to delete the local repo again and maybe open one of those broken files in a text editor to see whats inside. That may give you a hint whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

just create .m2 folder and run clean install command.